# Ajax send Post, and sending Canvas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

JavaScript:

```
var username = 'sami';
var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "Pic.php", false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(myImage);
ajax.send("q=" + encodeURIComponent(username));
```

PHP:

```
<? php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) {
    $user = $_POST['q'];
    $comp = $user.".png";
    $imageData = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $filteredData = substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",") + 1);
    $unencodedData = base64_decode($filteredData);
    $fp = fopen($comp, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose($fp);
} ?>
```

This is the  Code, The problem is that i couldn't get the user with post, when image saves its ".png" only....

Answer (score 0):

Send your request only once and pack both variables in the same send.
It does not make sense to send twice with different variables...

You should also check if the variable exists, serverside, isset($_POST['q']).

Another solution might be to add user as a GET variable to the url like: "Pic.php?q="+username and handle a GET variable for the username instead

Answer (score 0):

Like apelsinapa says, you have to pack them together:

```
ajax.send("img=" + myImage + "&user=" + user);
```

This, of course, would mean that you invalidate the "application/upload", because now you're back to form-encoding.

So again, like was mentioned, if you allow a query-string (`$_GET`) parameter denoting user or preferred file-name, or whatever, you can keep your application upload, and also have the filename.

```
ajax.open("POST", "Pic.php?user=" + user + "&fname=" + filename, true);
// leave headers as you have set them
// event-handlers here
ajax.send(myImage);
```